# javascript's onclick function with non-numeric characters

Tags: javascript

So I am updating a textbox with a value with this.

```
<a id="searchmykad" href="#" onclick="updatemykad(LUIS_34_awp);return false;">Persons name</a>
```

This would return an error

```
LUIS_34_awp is not defined
```

This on the other hand:

```
<a id="searchmykad" href="#" onclick="updatemykad(34);return false;">Persons name</a>
```

Would work.

```
function updatemykad(mykad) {
 $('#asd3').value(mykad).trigger("input");  
                       }
```

Am I not able to use non-numeric characters?

Comment: You need to wrap LUIS_34_awp in quotes like 'LUIS_34_awp'

Answer (score 3):

you were missing quotes `'`

```
<a id="searchmykad" href="#" onclick="updatemykad('LUIS_34_awp');return false;">Persons name</a>
```

without quotes it would have tried to search for `LUIS_34_awp` as a variable and hence gave the error that you got

Answer (score 2):

when params are strings, wrap them with '' or ""

Answer (score 0):

use your non-numeric characters with single quotes('').

```
<a id="searchmykad" href="#" onclick="updatemykad('LUIS_34_awp');return false;">Persons name</a>
```

this will help you.

thanks.